# take x photos every x minutes

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am using react-native with expo-camera.I want to take x photos every x minutes.

```
async snapPhoto() {
    if (this.camera) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.state.count; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          const { uri } = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(this.cameraOptions);
          let saveResult = await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri, 'photo');
          this.setState({ cameraRollUri: saveResult, path: uri })
        }, this.state.setTime * i);
      }
    }
  }
```

I receive a red screen on my device: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function[error on my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgBSr.png)

Comment: just change this line `setTimeout(function () {` to `setTimeout( async function () {`

Comment: I made the changes, now, I have a warning now every time I call the function: ```[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.camera.takePictureAsync')]
````

Comment: @Akhilesh  it is not enter to execute the function inside the setTimeOut

Answer (score 0):

You should add **async** after **setTimeout(**, see these code:

```
async snapPhoto() {
    if (this.camera) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.state.count; i++) {
        setTimeout(async function () {
          const { uri } = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(this.cameraOptions);
          let saveResult = await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri, 'photo');
          this.setState({ cameraRollUri: saveResult, path: uri })
        }, this.state.setTime * i);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I made the changes, now, I have a warning now every time I call the function: ```[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.camera.takePictureAsync')]
````

Comment: it is not enter in the function setTimeout(async function () {

Comment: it is not enter to execute the function inside the setTimeOut

Comment: The setTimeout uses `this.state.setTime` as a duration, but you set the state `this.setState({ cameraRollUri: saveResult, path: uri }` which remove the setTime variable. Try to change the code to `this.setState(state => Object.assign({}, state, { cameraRollUri: saveResult, path: uri }));`

Comment: it is always the same problem :/